# Boost 1.80.0 compiled libraries with -fvisibility=hidden creating issues

Tags: boost

I'm compiling boost sources 1.80.0 to generate static libraries and by default boost uses these options :

`-fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fvisibility=hidden`

This caused error on run time in our shared libraries of the project with undefined symbols.
After analyzing the issue we found that visibility need to be global not local.

I tried to recompile using:
./b2 --prefix=../build_local --exec-prefix=../build_local --build-type=complete variant=release link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned -d+2 **local-visibility=global** cxxflags=-fPIC  --without-python -a install

also

./b2 --prefix=../build_local --exec-prefix=../build_local --build-type=complete variant=release link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned -d+2 cxxflags=-fPIC **-fvisibility=default**  --without-python -a install

but b2 continue to build all libraries with `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fvisibility=hidden`.

Any help please on how to achieve this.

Compiler GCC 4.4.8

OS : Linux RHEL 7

Comment: What specific symbols are causing linking problems? There could be a bug in that particular library that needs to be reported.

Comment: There is no linking error, only a run time error. We are currently using 1.70, we only changed from boost 1.70 to 1.80. Our project have many .so files and only 2 contains boost libraries. When we investigate using nm command, the only difference was in boost libraries added to our shared so linraries. In the previous one, we have T visibility, but in 1.80 we have t. Looking at the output of b2 command, we found that it use -fvisibility=hidden

Comment: Good research. What is the `T` in question? In general you should not link Boost statically in more than one dynamic library. Ifyou do you _really want_ Boosts symbols tot be hidden because otherwise you run into ODR issues with any other library that statically links (some version) of Boost

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: if the error is around destructors (which is a typical issue that arises when having duplicated statics in several dynamic modules) then it will help to ensure that the object is destructed in the same module that constructed it. Smart pointers can help here, but another typical idiom is to have a "free_XXXX" function.

Comment: Thanks @sehe , I would agree with you in general but in this case it's a leagcy code with half million lines of code so I don't want to introduce any regression in any component.

Comment: As long as you have tests and very controlled deployment/config management! Thanks for posting the workaround that solves any short-term issues others may/will run into as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `cxxflags=-fvisibility=default` , here complete command :

```
./b2 --prefix=../build_local --exec-prefix=../build_local --build-type=complete variant=release link=static runtime-link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned -d+2 cxxflags=-fPIC cxxflags=-fvisibility=default --without-python -a install
```

For readability:

```bash
./b2                                \
    --prefix=../build_local         \
    --exec-prefix=../build_local    \
    --build-type=complete           \
      variant=release               \
      link=static                   \
      runtime-link=static           \
      threading=multi               \
    --layout=versioned              \
    -d+2                            \
      cxxflags=-fPIC                \
      cxxflags=-fvisibility=default \
    --without-python                \
    -a install
```

`-d+2` option allow us to see executed commands with all options.